# Equivalent of React's useLayoutEffect in Svelte

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, svelte, svelte-4

I'm porting a React hook to Svelte 4. The hook uses React's useLayoutEffect. According to the React docs:

> useLayoutEffect is a version of useEffect that fires before the browser repaints the screen.

Is there an simple way to replicate this functionality in Svelte either through a built in utility or with a custom function?

Answer (score -1):

The closest equivalent is Svelte's [onMount function](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#onmount).